# Can closed questions still earn badges?

Tags: support, closed-questions, badges

I've asked a couple (OK. A few) questions that have been closed. I've noticed that they still seem to gather additional "views". Can closed questions still earn badges? And, no, I'm not sure if I tagged this question correctly.

Comment: I've tagged it discussion instead, as I doubt you mean to report a bug.

Comment: @Keen Thank you. I got all turned around when it wouldn't accept my question and said it needed a 'bug feature-request discussion support' tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, closed questions behave normally except for one thing: you can't post an answer to a closed question. You can still earn badges for votes or views on a closed question, or an answer to a closed question.

Questions that are closed for reasons other than being a duplicate are normally deleted after a while. When a question is deleted, you stop earning any badge for it, but any badge already earned is not taken away.

For more information, see [How do “badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work) on the main meta site.

Comment: Removed the bit about the makeup badge rule, which was [removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81013/nice-answer-badge-roulette/187740#187740) some time ago